# I'm making an 8ball command, but python won't let me add a number to the command

Tags: discord.py

I'm making an 8ball command, but python won't let me add a number to the command.
What I want to make:

```
@client.command()
async def 8ball(ctx, args):
    #code here
```

Error:

```
  File "main.py", line 631
    async def 8ball(ctx, args=None):
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Having a number as the first character is very illegal (but for real, eight_ball(ctx, args): would work)

Comment: is there any way i can make it so that I can put a number?

Comment: Sadly that is a python-restriction

Comment: so i would have to do a on message event ?

Comment: you could add an alias to the command like:
@client.command(aliases="8ball") 
that might work

Comment: when i add that it gives me an error saying:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 633, in <module>
    async def eb(ctx, args=None):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1256, in decorator
    result = command(*args, **kwargs)(func)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1422, in decorator
    raise TypeError('Callback is already a command.')
TypeError: Callback is already a command.

Comment: Seems like an error in a different part of your program (the eb function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Aliases. Aliases can be thought of as other names the command can be called through.

```
@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, args):
    #code here
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 633, in <module>
    async def _8ball(ctx, args=None):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1256, in decorator
    result = command(*args, **kwargs)(func)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1422, in decorator
    raise TypeError('Callback is already a command.')
TypeError: Callback is already a command.

Comment: You probably have multiple decorators on the command.

Comment: There's no need to create an alias, the `command` decorator has a [`name` parameter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.command) that sets the command name instead of using the function name. Ex: `@client.command(name='8ball')`